# 'grep' command not working on Lubuntu

Tags: grep

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 with a fresh install (Monday) and I noticed that my `grep` command doesn't work. Whatever I do, it shows me the `grep usage page`. For instance, if I try to run: `grep test *` or `grep test test.txt`, I get the usage page. Command `which grep` returns `/bin/grep`, I also tried `alias grep="grep"` but nothing works.

`ls -l /bin/grep` prints:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 178216 jan. 18  2014 /bin/grep
```

Reinstalling the `grep` command with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grep
```

didn't make any difference.

The usage message is 76 lines long; the first few lines are:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input.
PATTERN is, by default, a basic regular expression (BRE).
Example: grep -i 'hello world' menu.h main.c
```

`grep --version` shows:

```
grep (GNU grep) 2.16
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /bin/grep`

Comment: `ls -l /bin/grep` prints `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 178216 jan. 18  2014 /bin/grep`

Comment: try reinstalling the grep `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grep`

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You haven't told us exactly what the "grep usage page" is. Please update your question to show the exact output. If it's too long show just the first few lines. And what does `grep --version` print?

Comment: the usage page is this: http://pastebin.com/Y2BnGzyX and grep version is `grep (GNU grep) 2.16`

Comment: It's going to be much more useful if the relevant information is in the question itself rather than in comments. I've just submitted an edit to include the first few lines of the usage message; I expect it will be approved and become visible soon. Once that shows up, I suggest updating the question to show the output of `grep --version` (if it's the same as the usage message, just say so).

Comment: Please run [this script](http://pastebin.com/ckcvY4M5) and show the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not showing the usage page, it shows the long --help page.

The only way i managed to replicate your grep behavior was to set GREP_OPTIONS="--help"

Try `unset GREP_OPTIONS` and do `env|less` and look for other environment variables that might have to be `unset`.

You might also want to check your `.profile`,`/etc/profile`,`.bashrc`, and so on for variables that can cause this.

Comment: Thank you very much feitingen that was it! I don't know what cause this  but at least it works now.